# Parsing XML tag attribute works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xml-parsing, rss

So I have an rss feed and am trying to read the *url* attribute from the *media:thumbnail* tag. The following code works perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome, where it only logs *undefined*.

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:url,
      dataType:'xml',
      success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).find("media\\:thumbnail").attr('url'))
             });
            }
          });
```

I've searched the internet for hours without success. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and [getElementsbyTagNameNS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/vf-eIAZ3e4s) seemed to be the best solution (works both in Firefox and Chrome):

```
var xmlhttp;
var img;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

        var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (i = 0; i<items.length;i++){

            img= items[i].getElementsByTagNameNS("*","thumbnail")[0].getAttribute('url');


            }
        }



    }
}
```